# Remove Container fluid padding specially in React-Bootstrap in Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am practicing a grid layout in react-bootstrap. But got stuck when I was trying to remove the padding of the container fluid. We can do that in regular bootstrap by overriding the container-fluid class and making the padding 0 as important.

```
.container-fluid {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

***I tried this way and it worked well but I don't want to use `!important` as I may have many container-fluid in my application later.***

```
<Container fluid>
      <Row noGutters>
        <Col lg={6} md={6} xs={12}>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>hello i am subrato</div>
        </Col>
        <Col lg={6} md={6} xs={12}>
          <div style={{ background: "blue" }}>I new to react-bootstrap</div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row noGutters>
        <Col xs={12} md={8}>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>hello i am subrato</div>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} md={4}>
          <div style={{ background: "blue" }}>I new to react-bootstrap</div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
</Container>
```

See my output here

[image]

How can I specifically select that container in react-bootstrap?

Comment: It seems to be working for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-playground-forked-xezyk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No it will not work @GonzaloFaus. see my answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo Hola!! I already did with `!important` and it worked well but I don't want to use `!important`. Is there any other way to remove the padding?

Comment: Worked aswell removing the !important property.

Comment: No, it's not working if we remove the import URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added a `className="p-0"` to my container fluid and it worked well. If we want to use regular bootstrap then we can use it by specifying the classes in `className`.
The main reason why I do inline-style because **Inline-style has high specificity than the internal as well as external style**.

It is like `inline-style > internal style > external style` in term of specificity.

```
<Container fluid={true} className="p-0">
      <Row noGutters>
        <Col lg={6} md={6} xs={12}>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>hello i am subrato</div>
        </Col>
        <Col lg={6} md={6} xs={12}>
          <div style={{ background: "blue" }}>I new to react-bootstrap</div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
</Container>
```

Avoid using `!important` in your application. Use `!important` where you have selected the element `specifically`. For example

```
div p span{
 color: red !important;
}

span{
color: blue;
}
```

The text inside `div p span` will be red and the text in `span` is blue (here CSS of span didn't get override because of `div p span` specificity).

Answer (score -1):

Remove **noGutters** attribute from Row

```
<Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <Col lg={6} md={6} xs={12}>
          <div style={{ background: "red" }}>hello i am subrato</div>
        </Col>
        <Col lg={6} md={6} xs={12}>
          <div style={{ background: "blue" }}>I new to react-bootstrap</div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
</Container>
```

Comment: Nope didn't work, if I remove noGutter then there are spaces between the columns.